# Split string when comma is inserted and add it to a string array

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs

I have an input that converts strings into 'styled tags' when the user types a comma, then, when the form is submitted, the strings are pushed into an array called 'content'.

On the EJS views, I am printing the result like `<%= course.content %>` but the result I am getting is `'string1,string2,string3,string4'` and what I am after is that when is pushed into the array, each string must be a different element:

```
content ['string1','string2','string3','string4']
```

only then it will render properly in my views by looping the array. I want to achieve this by javaScript or jQuery only, please.

**UPDATE: this is how I am rendering in my view**

```
<ul>
   <% var i; for (i = 0; i < course.content.length; i++) { %>
     <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> <%= course.content %></li>
   <% }; %>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE: this is my route where this POST request is being done**

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  Course.create(req.body.course, function(err, course) {
     if (err) {
       req.flash("error", err.message);
       return res.redirect("back");
     }
       res.redirect("/courses/" + course.id);
  });
});
```

**SOLVED! by using split on the server side like this:**

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
   Course.create(req.body.course, function(err, course) {
     if (err) {
       req.flash("error", err.message);
       return res.redirect("back");
     } else {
       var content = req.body.course.content.toString().split(",");
       course.content = content;
       course.save();
       console.log(course.content);
       res.redirect("/courses/" + course.id);
     }
   });
});
```

Here is another solution in javaScript using **function beforesubmit() by @garry man** see below.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/gabonessi/pen/eXymKE)

Comment: `'string1,string2,string3,string4'.split(',')` will help

Comment: instead of printing  <%= course.content %> , you can actually run a loop through it                                                                                                          <% for (var i = 0; i content.length; i++) { 
    // do something
} %>

Comment: Thank you, but where? I want the strings to be separated before sending it to the DB, I tried adding .split(',') at the end of the creation of the tag but it doesnt solve it

Comment: @ShoyebMemon I am running a loop, but as there is only one element it prints 'string1,string2,string3,string4' instead of printing four separated elements

Comment: Post updated to show how I am rendering in my views

Comment: How are you retrieving the content param server side?

Comment: I think #hiddenInput contains the value , can you please check. Split them and store it in a new array

Comment: Have you tried debugging `req.body.course` and check its runtime value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Long way

Otherwise there's one work around is as many tags you enter, that much input elements you should generate.

For e.g. my input tags are `foo,bar` then 2 input tags will be generated like

```
                                                            Note square brackets below
<input id="hiddenInput" type="hidden" name="course[content][]" required>
<input id="hiddenInput" type="hidden" name="course[content][]" required>
```

This is long way.

### Another way

If you submit form via AJAX, then you can manipulate data before submitting and convert string into array with the use of `.split(',')`.

### Another way (Server side)

Split string by `,` on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the problem is that you are submitting a form containing a single input which can only contain string values.

HTML Form practice is to have a single input for each array element to be posted, like:

```
<input name="course[content]"/> //value 1
<input name="course[content]"/> //value 2
<input name="course[content]"/> //value 3
```

So, in order to achieve that, before submit, you can call this function that generates those elements for you:

```
function beforesubmit(){
  let submitVal = document.getElementById('hiddenInput');
  let values  = submitVal.value.split(',');

  //let's get the container of the params passed to post
  let paramsContainer = submitVal.parentElement;
  // remove the param containting the string with commas as we're generating new ones
  paramsContainer.removeChild(submitVal); 

  for(let i =0; i<values.length;i++){
    //for each value, add a submit param containing each value
    let tmp = document.createElement('input');
    tmp.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    tmp.setAttribute('name','course[content]');
    tmp.setAttribute('value',values[i]);
    paramsContainer.appendChild(tmp);
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
}
```

in order to call this function, replace your `submit input` with this:

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="beforesubmit()">
```

Using this code you can already see the `POST` request difference between before and after. In your codepen it sends a single parameter, while with this snippet of code you are going to send an array of `course['content']`.

Now it's all up to how you are going retrieve data server side, you should be retrieving the `course['content']` param as an array.

Comment: Thank you, looks like a great solution! however, for some reason, my button input is not performing the onclick function and it does nothing. I have updated the codepen with your solution as I think is the right way to handle it. https://codepen.io/gabonessi/pen/eXymKE

Comment: you have to put the `beforesubmit()`function at the end of the js script, after the closing brackets `});`of the previous scope

Comment: of course... I did but it is now only submitting the last tag, also I realize it's only working when I select the form by tag name when I select with ID it does nothing.

Comment: Not really: the codepen above works perfectly. Check out the *NETWORK* tab in your developer console, watch for the sent form data. The problem persists in how you retrieve the results server-side. Can you post the code where you do that?

Comment: I have updated the post with how I retrieve the result on the server in my local app. In codepen if I check the network tab I see nothing. In the console I get  'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()' but what codepen interface is showing me after I submit is the last tag I entered: course {"content"=>"hello"}

Comment: I insist that your problem is server-side. Have a look at the network tab in this screenshot of mine: https://imgur.com/a/U4IfzIX  - you can definitely see the parameters are correctly passed. I will take a look at you server-side code and try understand what's going on, as I am not that familiar with EJS

Comment: I solved by using split on the server side, many thanks for all the time spent helping me, very much appreciated! I will post the solution in the post